# QFileDialog subclassed and selected directories, then files with a single click

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

With various documentations (especially on stackoverflow) I subclassed a QFileDialog and integrated a QTreeView. I inserted the class in question into a QTabWidget. It seems to work well with the mouse set to double click (the selection of images in the tree for example) but personally I have my mouse set to single click and there it is a problem. Currently (with the mouse set to single click) when I select and click on a directory everything appears as if I had finished (and selected a file), ... I would like to enter the directory and see its contents with the single click mouse and be able to select the image I want after.
In fact I'm trying to get the selection behavior that exists if we call QFileDialog.getOpenFileName.

I tried to provide a simplified script:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabWidget, QTreeView, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, \
                        QFileDialog, QPushButton, QAbstractItemView, \
                        QMainWindow, QApplication

import sys, platform


class FileOpen(QFileDialog) :

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FileOpen, self).__init__(parent)
    
        self.setOption(self.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
        self.setFileMode(self.ExistingFiles)
        self.setNameFilter("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)")
    
        if platform.system() == 'Windows' :
            self.setDirectory(QDir.rootPath()) # Windows
        if platform.system() == 'Linux' :
            self.setDirectory(QDir.homePath()) # GNU/Linux
        if platform.system() == 'Darwin' :
            self.setDirectory(QDir.homePath()) # MacOS
    
        button = self.findChildren(QPushButton)
        name_button = button[0].text().lower()
        print("button", button[0].text().lower())
        self.openButton = [x for x in button if name_button in str(x.text()).lower()][0]

        self.openButton.clicked.disconnect()
        self.openButton.clicked.connect(self.openClicked)
        self.tree = self.findChild(QTreeView)
    
        self.tree.setMaximumWidth(600)
        self.tree.setMinimumWidth(550)
    
        self.tree.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.tree.setHeaderHidden(True)
    
        self.tree.hideColumn(1)
        self.tree.hideColumn(2)
        self.tree.hideColumn(3)
    
        selmodel = self.tree.selectionModel()
        selmodel.selectionChanged.connect(self.selection_activated)


    def selection_activated(self) :
        self.file_capture()
    

    def openClicked(self) :
        self.file_capture()
    
    
    def file_capture(self) :
        modeleIndex = self.tree.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
        file_list = []
        for i in modeleIndex :
            if i.column() == 0 :
                file_list.append(os.path.join(str(self.directory().absolutePath()), str(i.data())))      
        self.selected_file = "".join(file_list)
        print("self.selected_file", self.selected_file)
        self.hide()
        return self.selected_file


class MainFileOpenTry(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainFileOpenTry, self).__init__()
    
        self.setWindowTitle('FileOpenTry')
    
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1000, 760)
        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 760)
    
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
    
        self.win_widget_1 = FileOpen(self)

        widget = QWidget()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
    
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.win_widget_1, "File Open Tab")
    
        layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
    
        self.f_open = FileOpen()
        self.f_open.selection_activated()
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainFileOpenTry()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you are missing `from os import path` also remove `self.hide()` in the `__init__()` method under `FileOpen` class

Comment: @JacksonPro : Hello, sorry for the late reply ... yes indeed it works better like that. Thanks for the comments. I have a few more quick questions to ask later.